# How to select a specific value from the initialState? React - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a reducer how can I select only the "lemon" value if the initState is an object like fruits and the value is another object -> initialFruitsState??

Like the following:

I tried like this `fruits['initialFruitsState']['lemon']: action.id,` but this did not work.

```
const initialFruitsState = {
  banana: 5,
  apple: 3,
  lemon: 4,
  watermelon: 2,
  mangoe: 7,
};

const initState = {
  fruits: initialFruitsState,
  vegetables: initialVegetablesState,
};

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_VALUE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fruits['initialFruitsState']['lemon']: action.id,
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I'm guessing you just want to update the lemon key on your state. In that case, you would need to do something like this.

```
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_VALUE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fruits: {
                    ...state.fruits,
                    lemon: action.id
                }
            };
        }
    }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: Sweet, this is what I was looking for. Thank you @Todd